# Need to check json value is empty python

Tags: python, json

I have json result as like as below I want to check and exit the script if anyone of the 'Route' key value is empty.

```
Value = [{"Route":[[{"Name":"abc.com","ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"1.1.1.1"}],"TTL":600,"Type":"A"}]]},
 {"Route":[[{"Name":"xyz.com","ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"1.1.2.3"}],"TTL":600,"Type":"A"}]]},
 {"Route":[[{"Name":"qaz,com","ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"1.1.2.4"}],"TTL":600,"Type":"A"}]]}]
```

Comment: Any attempts on your side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to check if any are empty

```
all(v['Route'] for v in Value)
```

Or if you need to interrupt iteration

```
for v in Value:
    if not v['Route']:
        exit_script()
    something_else()
```